# turn into 2d array index

Tags: javascript, arrays, formula

I have a array with `3*3` dimension(2d) like this:

```
a[3][3]=[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]];
```

I want formulate this array to access in single array(1d). how I can do this?
like:

```
 b[9]=[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9];
```

Comment: The original array doesn't have `0` in it. Where's that supposed to come from?

Comment: `a[3][3] = ...` and `b[9] = ...` don't make sense here.

Answer (score 1):

you want to convert a 2d array to a flat array. How about:

```
var a = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]];
var merged = [];
merged = merged.concat.apply(merged, a);
```

see https://stackoverflow.com/a/10865042/1432801

Answer (score 0):

```
var flatArray = [];
for(var i=0;i<a.length;i++){
    for(var j=0;j<a[i].length;j++){
        flatArray.push(a[i][j]);
    }
}
```